# Why my image cannot set as background image but other can?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an image upload to my server as below:
http://aurora-maker.com/AppsheetImage/TestingApplicationForm.jpg
The picture works very well but not sure why it cannot set as background image like below and display properly when opening the brower.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>   
Example of Background image  
</title>  
</head>  
<body background="http://aurora-maker.com/AppsheetImage/TestingApplicationForm.jpg">  
    
  
<h1>Hello</h1><h2>Everyone</h2></body>
</html>
```

another example works very well, just replace the image.THE SAME CODE. Any thoughts, thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>   
Example of Background image  
</title>  
</head>  
<body background="https://previews.123rf.com/images/kotenko/kotenko1403/kotenko140300008/26854631-snowy-winter-in-a-mountain-forest-sunny-cold-day-with-snow-covered-trees-carpathian-mountains-ukrain.jpg">  
    
  
<h1>Hello</h1><h2>Everyone</h2></body>
</html>
```

Comment: to use a url as image u need to set `background="url(http://aurora-maker.com/AppsheetImage/TestingApplicationForm.jpg)"` like https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Read documentation! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax: **background: url("http://aurora-maker.com/AppsheetImage/TestingApplicationForm.jpg");**

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Use below line `body`. It will work in your case.

```
style="background: url(http://aurora-maker.com/AppsheetImage/TestingApplicationForm.jpg);"
```

But to show this backgraound image in your site `http://aurora-maker.com/` you need to use below css as well because video tag override your background image of `body`.

```
#bg-video {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <title>Example of Background image</title>        
    </head>  
    <body style="background: url(http://aurora-maker.com/AppsheetImage/TestingApplicationForm.jpg);">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>Everyone</h2>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried copy <!DOCTYPE html>  ... </html> you provided to a notepad and save as a html. It still cannot show the background image when using brower to open. Is it something that I missed?